# Cordova: how do I get Google Play query parameters after app install?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, google-play, referrer

How do I get the REFERRER parameters from a Google Play install link in a Cordova 3.5 project?
I tried this plugin: https://github.com/tvhnet2014/PHONEGAP-android-referrer-plugin, but it did not work. It depends on https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/ -- Cordova doesn't seem to be able to compile the project after this plugin is added.

How do I get the REFERRER parameter from Google Play with Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Just use this other plugin for your AppPreferences:

https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences

then it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

The premise of the question is sound, but the plugin you want to use will not work for what you want to use it.

FYI, this plugin states:

"Don't forget when using this plugin that if an app is installed directly from Google Play, this plugin will not execute--the intent will never fire."

***Do not use the OP's mentioned plugin for direct Google Play installs!***

As for the actual question, I have been trying to get this working for hours but nothing that actually works so far... will update as appropriate.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I gave up. I don't know if they added a way.

Comment: I was able to solve it using apla's plugin and https://github.com/8zrealestate/android-referrer-plugin